# Creating an summary dataset with multiple objects and multiple observations per object

Tags: r

I have a dataset with the reports from a local shop, where each line has a client's ID, date of purchase and total value per purchase. 
I want to create a new plot where for each client ID I have all the purchases in the last month or even just sample purchases in a range of dates I choose. 
The main problem is that certain customers might buy once a month, while others can come daily - so the number of observations per period of time can vary.

I have tried subsetting my dataset to a specific range of time, but either I choose a specific date - and then I only get a small % of all customers, or I choose a range and get multiple observations for certain customers. 
(In this case - I wouldn't mind getting the earliest observation)

An important note: I know how to create a for loop to solve this problem, but since the dataset is over 4 million observations it isn't practical since it would take an extremely long time to run.

A basic example of what the dataset looks like:

```
   ID Date Sum
1   1    1 234
2   1    2  45
3   1    3   1
4   2    4 223
5   3    5 546
6   4    6  12
7   2    1  20
8   4    3  30
9   6    2   3
10  3    5  45
11  7    6 456
12  3    7  65
13  8    8 234
14  1    9  45
15  3    2   1
16  4    3 223
17  6    6 546
18  3    4  12
19  8    7  20
20  9    5  30
21 11    6   3
22 12    6  45
23 14    9 456
24 15   10  65
....
```

And the new data set would look something like this:

```
ID 1Date 1Sum 2Date 2Sum 3Date 3Sum
1  1     234  2     45   3     1
2  1     20   4     223  NA    NA
3  2     1    5     546  5     45
```

...

Thanks for your help!

Comment: So what's the desired result for this sample input? Where exactly are you getting stuck?

Comment: Please add the desired result to the question itself so it can be properly formatted rather than in the comments.

Comment: @MrFlick is this clearer?
I would really appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this with a bit if help from `dplyr` and `tidyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
dd %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(seq=1:n()) %>% 
  pivot_wider("ID", names_from="seq", values_from = c("Date","Sum"))
```

Where `dd` is your sample data frame above.